# Como Guardar varios id's en una Variable en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Necesito saber como guardar diferentes valores en una variable en MySQL. Requiero que en mi consulta en la variable que estoy declarando, se puedan guardar todos los Id's que obtengo como un arreglo y poder utilizarlo en la misma consulta o que se quede guardado en mi variable, ya que en este momento solo guarda el primer valor obtenido.

Esta es mi consulta, estoy declarando la variable y quiero que se guarden todos los resultados que se muestran en id viaje, pero solo se guarda el primer valor de la consulta.

```
    SET @id_viajes2:='';
    SELECT DISTINCT viaje.id_unidad,(max(viaje.id_viaje)) AS 'viaje',viaje.folio_int_viaje,viaje.fecha_viaje,unidad.eco,@id_viajes AS 'ids' FROM viaje LEFT JOIN unidad ON viaje.id_unidad=unidad.id_unidad WHERE viaje.id_empresa = 178 AND viaje.STATUS = 1 AND unidad.id_unidad IN(SELECT id_unidad FROM unidad WHERE id_empresa = 178 AND STATUS =1) AND YEAR(viaje.fecha_viaje)=2023 GROUP BY viaje.id_viaje ORDER BY viaje.id_viaje DESC
```

[image: Este es el resultado que obtengo con la consulta anterior]

Comment: Empecemos con que una variable, guarda un solo valor.. vos, que queres hacer con todos esos valores que supuestamente queres guardar??? porque probablemente no quieras una variable...

Comment: Con [`group_concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) podrías obtener una cadena de valores separados por delimitador.

Comment: y de dónde sale el valor 823413?

Comment: @gbianchi es que quiero utilizar todos esos valores en una consulta posterior, y tener disponibles estos valores.

Comment: @ffflabs El valor es el id del primer registros de la consulta, por eso necesito saber como guardar todos, asi como si fuera un arreglo

Comment: es que eso es lo que no entiendo. No veo que estés asignando `@id_viajes` en ninguna parte más que al inicializarla como un string vacío

Comment: ¿Y qué vas a hacer con ese arreglo después? Tienes algo mucho más potente en las manos, sólo que sigues pensando con mentalidad de programador. Cuéntanos y te ayudamos a pensar como un administrador de bases de datos

Comment: Si queres tener disponibles esos valores necesitas una tabla temporal.. estas pensando mal tu solucion...